# rails 3:how to generate models for existing database tables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I've configured my database.yml to point to my existing mysql database

how can I generate models from it?

```
rails generate model existing_table_name
```

only gives an emty model..

Comment: gives you an empty model? what does that mean? What are you trying to do? :)

Comment: i expected it to contain all fields and relations of that table, but all i get is an empty class that derives from ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: what you are doing is not possible unless you create your own scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Rails model doesn't show your fields, but you can still use them. Try the following. Assuming you have a Model named ModelName and a field called "name", fire up the Rails console and type:

```
ModelName.find_by_name('foo')
```

Given a name that exists in the DB, you should see results.

Rails doesn't infer relationships though, but if your database follows Rails conventions they are easily added.

**Update**

I've noticed this particular lack of explicitness ("magic") is a source of confusion for newbies to Rails. You can always look in `schema.rb` to see the models and all the fields in one place. Also, if you would prefer to see the schema for each model in the model file, you can use the [annotate_models](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem, which will put the db schema in a comment at the top of the model file.

Comment: Wow, thanks I never knew this could happen! ehhe. I learn something new today.

Comment: THe generated rails models show your fields in the attr_accessible call.

Answer (score 15):

You can try [Rmre](https://rubygems.org/gems/rmre). It can create models for existing schema and it tries to create all relationships based on foreign keys information.

Comment: I tried Rmre but it created only the relationships between the models (e.g. has_many, belongs_to). It did not create the model attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is:

```
$ rake db:schema:dump
```

That will set a new `db/schema.db` to create a schema of your DB.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord doesn't parse a schema definition. It asks the DBM for the table defs and figures out the fields on the fly.

Having the schema is useful if you are going to modify the tables via migrations. 
[`Schema Dumping and You`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) will help you dump it to use as a reference for building migrations.

ActiveRecord makes some suppositions about the table naming and expects an `id` field to be the primary key with a sequential number as the type. Having the migrations would help you to refactor the tables and/or fieldnames and types, but you can do those same things via your DBM's command-line. You don't really have to follow ActiveRecord's style but doing so helps avoid odd errors and lets AR infer things to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Could try [Magic Model Generator](http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/)

Comment: Note: Is for Rails 2, no Rails 3 available.

Comment: Does anyone know of any alternative methods that generate models with relationships, etc from existing schema in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rare_map gem.
https://github.com/wnameless/rare_map
It works both on Rail 3 and 4.