# How can I migrate data from Core Data to Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, core-data, core-data-migration

I've created an application which contains Core Data entities with many-to-many relationships, programmatically compiled and linked from various sources on the web (JSON / Parse.com) which I use in my application.

It takes about 30 minutes to import all the data and generate all the relationships and data and compile this to Core Data (sqlite).

I've already create the app and preloaded the sqlite database which is shipped with the app. My plan now however is migrating this data to Ruby on Rails.

Is it possible to take the .sqlite and import this in Ruby On Rails and just create the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question here:
[rails 3:how to generate models for existing database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119659/rails-3how-to-generate-models-for-existing-database-tables)

Which will lead you to that gem:
https://rubygems.org/gems/rmre

I haven't tried it by myself but it seems like a good way.
If you want just to generate migrations for existing DB you can read this post:
https://hackhands.com/ruby-rails-tutorial-creating-rails-instance-existing-mysql-db/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try :)